# Extract the raster values for geometry using Python

Tags: python, raster, geometry, rasterio, indexing

I tried to extract the pixel value of the raster for the points with the following code.

```
for point in df['geometry']:
    x = point.xy[0][0]
    y = point.xy[1][0]
    row, col = raster.index(x,y) 
    print("Point correspond to row, col: %d, %d"%(row,col))
    print("Raster value on point %.2f \n"%raster.read(1)[row,col])
```

but I got the error saying: `index 332238 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1543`.

I tried to resolve this by applying the following conditions. Code ran successfully but didn't print anything.

```
#extract point value from raster
for point in df['geometry']:
    x = point.xy[0][0]
    y = point.xy[1][0]
    row, col = raster.index(x,y) 
    if raster.index(x,y=332238):
      continue;
    print("Point correspond to row, col: %d, %d"%(row,col))
    print("Raster value on point %.2f \n"%raster.read(1)[row,col])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is probably due to the fact you are using coordinates as indices. You need to calculate the correct indices using origin and pixel size.

It is easier to use [rasterstats](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

raster = r"/home/bera/GIS/Data/TM_geotiff/nh_62_6.tif"
df = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/randompoints.shp")
df["rastervalue"] = [x["mean"] for x in zonal_stats(vectors=df["geometry"], raster=raster, stats="mean")]

 #  id                        geometry  rastervalue
 # 0.0  POINT (608779.447 6289491.427)     0.236735
 # 1.0  POINT (605444.846 6285629.711)     4.634330
 # 2.0  POINT (607708.951 6288215.687)     0.201943
 # 3.0  POINT (604552.898 6290783.196)    17.533873
 # 4.0  POINT (605545.128 6291401.151)    17.047264
```